# Check if VirtualFreeEx has been completed/executed

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, memory-management

I use VirtualAllocEx on a remote process to reserve some space like this:

```
VirtualAllocEX (RemoteProcessHandle, nil, SizeInBytes, MEM_COMMIT or MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
```

Then I "fill"/write the allocated addressspace with `WriteProcessMemory`

Then I properly use

```
VirtualFreeEx (RemoteProcessHandle, Address, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
```

to release the allocated space.

Is it possible to check on the Address of `VirtualAllocEx` **after** `VirtualFreeEx` has been called to check if `VirtualFreeEx` was successful?

Comment: The [`VirtualFreeEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366894(v=vs.85).aspx) function returns BOOL, so just check that value when you call it.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't precise enough. I meant is it possible to check it after VirtualFreeEx has been called. (say another thread wants to check if this space has been recently freed by VirtualFreeEx

Comment: You can use VirtualQueryEx to determine whether the address is allocated or free.  But if the address *is* allocated there's no way to tell whether that's your allocation or someone else's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As soon as you return the address to the system, any future reference of that address is invalid. Once you have made the successful call to `VirtualFreeEx`, you must not refer to `Address` again. Once you have returned the address to the system, the system owns it. The only way for that address to become valid in the future, is through another call to `VirtualAllocEx`.

Comment: Thanks. I just didn't know that the system actually owns that address in the future :/

Comment: @BenjaminWeiss any memory that is not used by any process or resource is actually owned by system, Actually MMU handles and keep track of all the memory committed/reserved or freed back to system so that system can manage memory efficiently.